# Trying to take a user input and put it into a file, but cannot get it out of the entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a college project and I am building a DnD assistant for it. I am trying to take the user's input and transfer it into a file, however, it no work...

I do not have a lot of experience in the field, so I do not know what is wrong with this code. If anyone could help, please do. I am trying to take the user input and print it out using a button

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root2=tk.Tk()
F2=Frame(root2)
F2.pack(
    ipadx=100,
    ipady=100
    )
def getItTogether():
    global playerName
    string = playerName.get()
    print (string)
global playerName
playerName = Entry(root2, width= 10)
playerName.place(x=70,y=100)
Button(root2,text="pull your stuff together tkinter", command = getItTogether()).pack()
```

Comment: You are calling `getItTogether()` during startup of your program, and passing its return value (which is None) as the action to be performed when the Button is clicked.  You just want `command = getItTogether`, without the parentheses, to pass *the function itself* to the Button for later use.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is:

```
Button(root2,text="pull your stuff together tkinter", command = getItTogether).pack()
```

and you should be fine.
The problem was, that you called the function when defining the button. Just remove the () from the command = getItTogether.